# Loading different external CSS files and external JavaScript files in the <head> tag and at the bottom of the <body> tag in React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, laravel

I am pretty new to React and I am doing some experiment to learn it more properly. Currently, I am converting a HTML/CSS/JavaScript template into React. I previously used to simply put the external CSS and JavaScript files in the *index.html* file itself, like this:

```html
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/admin-template/assets/vendor/fonts/boxicons.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/admin-template/assets/vendor/fonts/fontawesome.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/admin-template/assets/vendor/fonts/flag-icons.css"/>
</head>
<body>
---------------------
---------------------
---------------------
---------------------
    <script src="%PUBLIC_URL%/admin-template/assets/vendor/js/script1.js"></script>
    <script src="%PUBLIC_URL%/admin-template/assets/vendor/js/script2.js"></script>
</body>
```

But then I realized two things:

1. It is not the right thing to do.
2. If I have to use multiple templates, like one for the admin panel
   and one for the front end side, I can simply put all the CSS, JavaScript,
   etc. content in the *index.html* file like this. Since React is a [single-page application](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application), there is a high chance that putting all CSS, JavaScript, etc. content
   in the *index.html* file will cause a major clash/conflict among the
   external files.

So I discovered this approach:

```javascript
import { useEffect } from 'react';

function PreLoginHeaderScript() {

    useEffect(() => {
        var baseUrl             = process.env.REACT_APP_PUBLIC_URL;

        // CSS //
        const cssBoxIcon        = document.createElement('link');
        cssBoxIcon.id           = 'boxicon-css';
        cssBoxIcon.href         = baseUrl + 'admin-template/assets/vendor/fonts/boxicons.css';
        cssBoxIcon.rel          = 'stylesheet';
        cssBoxIcon.type         = 'text/css';

        // Scripts //
        const scriptHelper   = document.createElement('script');
        scriptHelper.id      = 'helper-script';
        scriptHelper.src     = baseUrl + 'admin-template/assets/vendor/js/helpers.js';
        scriptHelper.async   = true;

        if (!document.getElementById('boxicon-css')) {
            // Loading CSS in the head
            document.head.appendChild(cssBoxIcon);
        }
        if (!document.getElementById('helper-script')) {
            // Loading script at the end of the body
            document.body.appendChild(scriptHelper);
        }
    }, []);

}

export default PreLoginHeaderScript;
```

This approach is working like a charm. The result is like this:

```html
<head>
    ---------------------
    ---------------------
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost:5052/admin-template/assets/vendor/fonts/boxicons.css"/>
</head>
<body>
---------------------
---------------------
---------------------
---------------------
    <script src="http://localhost:5052/admin-template/assets/vendor/js/helpers.js"></script>
</body>
```

However, I want to make it more refined by using the stack/push concept of Laravel in it. In Laravel, one can declare stacks like this:

```html
<head>
    ---------------------
    ---------------------
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{asset('admin-template/assets/vendor/fonts/boxicons.css')}}"/>
    @stack('css')
</head>
<body>
---------------------
---------------------
---------------------
---------------------
    <script src="{{asset('admin-template/assets/vendor/js/helpers.js')}}"></script>
    @stack('script')
</body>
```

Now if someone wants to push external CSS files in the stack 'css', he/she just needs to use the [LOC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_lines_of_code) like this:

```
@push('css')
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{asset('admin-template/assets/vendor/fonts/flagicons.css')}}"/>
@endpush
```

Similarly, to add an external JavaScript file, one can do it like this:

```
@push('script')
    <script src="{{asset('admin-template/assets/vendor/js/misc.js')}}"></script>
@endpush
```

As such, the resultant HTML becomes like this:

```html
<head>
    ---------------------
    ---------------------
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost/test-laravel/admin-template/assets/vendor/fonts/boxicons.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost/test-laravel/admin-template/assets/vendor/fonts/flagicons.css"/>
</head>
<body>
---------------------
---------------------
---------------------
---------------------
    <script src="http://localhost/test-laravel/admin-template/assets/vendor/js/helpers.js"></script>
    <script src="http://localhost/test-laravel/admin-template/assets/vendor/js/misc.js"></script>
</body>
```

The difference is that in `document.head.appendChild(cssBoxIcon);` or `document.body.appendChild(scriptHelper);` the CSS/scripts are appended just before the ending of the <head> or <body> tags. But the Laravel stack/push method allows one to push CSS or scripts content at any position where the stack with the provided name has been defined.

How can I do this in React?